# glib on Symbian S60

Tags: c, symbian, s60, glib

I am interested in porting a C library that depends on glib to Symbian.

After some research, I found that there is a Symbian port of glib. However I can't seem to find much documentation about it. Can anyone point me to the right direction as to whether this can be even done or not? If yes, how.

Comment: @skaffman, reverted your tag edit. This one is about Glib, not GNU LIBC (glibc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Forum Nokia](http://www.forum.nokia.com) has a lot of resources for developing for Nokia/S60 devices.

The glib port is part of the [Open C/C++ plug-ins](http://www.forum.nokia.com/info/sw.nokia.com/id/91d89929-fb8c-4d66-bea0-227e42df9053/Open_C_SDK_Plug-In.html). Download and install them on top of your SDK to get started.